# Mockito when().thenReturn not being overriden

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a unit test which looks something like this

```
public class TdsConfigTest {

@InjectMocks
TdsConfig tdsConfig;

@Mock
Configuration config;

@BeforeMethod
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    Mockito.when(config.getInt(SettlementConstants.TDS_LIMIT, SettlementConstants.DEFAULT_TDS_LIMIT)).thenReturn(10000);
    Mockito.when(config.getInt(SettlementConstants.NEW_TDS_LIMIT, 10000)).thenReturn(0);
    Mockito.when(config.getInt(SettlementConstants.TDS_PERCENT_VALUE, SettlementConstants.DEFAULT_TDS_PERCENT_VALUE)).thenReturn(30);
    Mockito.when(config.getInt(SettlementConstants.NEW_TDS_PERCENT_VALUE, 30)).thenReturn(20);
}

@Test
public void returnsValidPercentBeforeCutoff() {
    mockFutureTdsCutoff();
    assertEquals(30, tdsConfig.getTdsPercentage());
    assertNotEquals(20, tdsConfig.getTdsPercentage());
}

@Test
public void returnsValidTdsLimitBeforeCutoff() {
    mockFutureTdsCutoff();
    assertEquals(10000, tdsConfig.getTdsLimit());
    assertNotEquals(0, tdsConfig.getTdsLimit());
    Mockito.reset();
}

@Test
public void returnsValidPercentAfterCutoff() {
    mockPastTdsCutoff();
    assertEquals(20, tdsConfig.getTdsPercentage());
    assertNotEquals( 30, tdsConfig.getTdsPercentage());
}

@Test
public void returnsValidLimitAfterCutoff() {
    mockPastTdsCutoff();
    assertEquals(tdsConfig.getTdsLimit(), 0);
    assertNotEquals(tdsConfig.getTdsLimit(), 10000);
}


private Instant getFutureInstant() {
    return Instant.now().plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
}

private Instant getPastInstant() {
   return Instant.now().minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
}

private void mockFutureTdsCutoff() {
    Instant futureMs = getFutureInstant();
    Mockito.when(config.getLong(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(futureMs.toEpochMilli());
}

private void mockPastTdsCutoff() {
    Mockito.when(config.getLong(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(getPastInstant().toEpochMilli());
}
}
```

The functions in the first two tests should use future Instant as mocked and the last two tests should use past Instant as mocked

Here, the first two tests fail while the other two tests pass.
When I went to debug, I found out that in the first two tests, the mock is returning past Instant instead of future Instant.

When I setup debugging points, it looks like the tests are run down-top [ last test runs first and first test run last ]. This means that `mockFutureTdsCutoff()` is not mocking a future date as expected but instead it is using the mock that was initialized first which is `mockPastTdsCutoff()` since the last test was executed first everytime.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: How is `TdsConfig` implemented?

Comment: Why do you init the mocks for each test? I guess that the setup method you want to be run only once for all your class. Looks like you should use the @BeforeTest annotation of testng instead of the BeforeMethod

Comment: @Carlos I understand that, but the issue is with the `mockFutureTdsCutoff` and `mockPastTdsCutoff` right? When I call `mockFutureTdsCutoff` any `Mock.when` with that particular signature has to be overriden right?